# Magento2.2.6 Admin Session Timeout Not Working

Tags: magento2.2.6, core-session

Something is wrong with the admin session timeout in **Magento2.2.6**. I have everything set to 1 day however it's all ignored. I get logged out if I'm inactive for 15 minutes. I have `vendor/magento/module-encryption-key/etc/config.xml` set to `86400` and here are screenshots of my PHP and admin settings and my cookie which shows an expiration date of tomorrow but I will have to login again despite everything appearing to be setup correctly, what else am I missing?

[image: Admin session timeout]

[image: PHP Settings]

[image: Cookie Shows Tommorrow]

Comment: See its Magento2 default bug : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10594#issuecomment-349762653

Comment: @AmitNaraniwal that's not my problem. As you can see in the screenshot my gc_maxlifetime is set to 86400 already. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should also try it by changing the following PHP INI varibles:

```
session.gc_divisor = 100
session.gc_probability = 1
```

For more details check: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor

Answer (score 0):

@MageAj your answer got me in the right direction. It wasn't the actual solution but it led me to the problem. Once I set gc_divisor and gc_probability I found that Magento was unable to write to the php default session path which was set to the following:

```
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70"
```

So I edited env.php and added save_path to the session section as follows:

```
'session' => [
        'save' => 'files',
        'save_path' => '/home/<user>/<magento_dir>/var/session'
    ],
```

Another solution might be to change from files to db for session storage.

Answer (score 0):

I set `session.gc_divisor` and `session.gc_probability` as stated above, and also added the save path in `env.php`. At first, it didn't work, but I was no longer seeing the permission denied error. Then, after several hours of trying different things, I discovered my admin session lifetime setting had somehow reverted back to 900. Tried this again and it worked.